# Using a different shader for each pixel in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader

I'm trying to write a deferred renderer in OpenGL that supports multiple materials (different lighting models etc.) and layered materials (different materials blended together).

I'm writing the material ID to a g-buffer as well as the standard vertex attribute g-buffers. How would I use a different shader for each pixel in the second stage (when the lighting is calculated and rendered to the screen)?

I thought about using a compute shader to make a list of pixels for each material ID then generating a mixture of quads, points, and maybe lines out of it and then reading these meshes back to the CPU and  rendering them with their respective materials. I think this would be a bit slow the mesh has to be read and written back each frame.

Answer (score 2):

A. Write an **uber-shader** that chooses exact shader path based on pixel MaterialID attribute. That could work well for multiple materials. That uber-shader could consist of several sections stitched together programatically, to simplify development.

B. **Reduce materials count.** Speaks for itself.

C. Add **more channels** to your g-buffer to store varying material parameters (e.g. Specular)

D. Do multiple passes with different shaders and **use MaterialID as a sort of "stencil"** to either render if it's matching material and shader or `discard;` to skip the pixel ASAP.

You can combine these solutions as well.

Comment: It should be noted that GPUs usually don't work very well with dynamic branching, and having many branches can result in lowered performances.

Comment: @Kromster Wouldn't just using discard still be slow since my GPU would still be rasterizing a full screen quad (2 million pixels) for every materials only to discard 90% of the pixels (I'm not sure how discard works. If more pixels are discarded wouldn't the render still take the same time because the GPU is a parallel processor?). And how does a stencil work? Sorry if I'm asking really simple questions.

Comment: @CasparValentine it all depends on your use case. You didn't show any specific use-cases and specific hardwares. Thus I can not post any specific answers. Test and try! )